# Converting digits from string into words

Tags: java, string, loops, char

The goal of this assignment for my cs class is to search a string for digits and change them to the written form

ex: `4 -> four`

It's a relatively simple task.  I have two problems however:

1) due to my current code if I convert a string of just **"8"** and try and make it **"eight"**, it won't work because it's longer than the current length of the string.

2) dealing with more than one number char in a row through the string.  I have it somewhat figured out.  If you run what I have with certain `Strings` it works.  We're supposed to separate more than one number char with a hyphen.

Here is my code:

```
public class NumberConversion {

    /**
     * * Class Constants **
     */
    /**
     * * Class Variables **
     */

    /* No class variables are needed due to the applet not having a state.
     All it does is simply convert. */
    /**
     * * Class Arrays **
     */
    char numberChar[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    String numbers[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};

    /**
     * * Accessor Methods **
     */
    /**
     * * Transformer/Mutator Methods **
     */
    public void writeNumber(String phrase) {
        /**
         * Local Variables *
         */
        String newPhrase = "";
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;

        phrase = phrase.trim();

        /**
         * * Counts through the length of phrase **
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
            /**
             * * If the current char is a number char, enter the next repitition
             * structure **
             */
            int l = i + 1;

            if (isNumber(phrase.charAt(i)) && isNumber(phrase.charAt(i + 1))) {
                boolean searchArray = true;

                do {
                    if (numberChar[ j] == phrase.charAt(i)) {
                        searchArray = false;
                    }

                    j++;

                } while (searchArray && j < numberChar.length);

                phrase = phrase.replace(Character.toString(phrase.charAt(i)), numbers[ j - 1] + "-"); //error HERE

            }

            if (isNumber(phrase.charAt(i))) {
                boolean searchArray = true;

                do {
                    /**
                     * * Counts through numberChar array to see which char was
                     * found in the phrase. Stops when found **
                     */
                    if (numberChar[ k] == phrase.charAt(i)) {
                        searchArray = false;
                    }

                    k++;

                } while (searchArray && k <= numberChar.length);

                /**
                 * * Changes char to string and replaces it with the matching
                 * String numbers array element **
                 */
                phrase = phrase.replace(Character.toString(phrase.charAt(i)), numbers[ k - 1]);
            }
            phrase = phrase.replace("- ", " ");
        }
        System.out.println(phrase); // Prints the changed phrase.
    }

    /**
     * * Helper Methods **
     */
    /**
     * * Observer Methods **
     */
    public boolean isNumber(char input) {
        boolean isNumber = false; // Initially fails

        for (int i = 0; i < numberChar.length; i++) {
            /**
             * * If input matches a number char, method returns true **
             */
            if (input == numberChar[ i]) {
                isNumber = true;
            }
        }
        return isNumber;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add examples your code worked for and examples where it failed and how it failed...

Comment: @acdcjunior : The language is Java.

Comment: @Lion: Okay. When the OP stated "The goal of this assignment for my **cs** class", he led me into thinking it was C#. `System.out.println` gives it away, though.

Comment: What are the inputs that work and what are the inputs that don't work? And what are the errors or wrong outputs you get?

Comment: if there is a number `34` how do you want to print it like `ThreeFour` or `Three Four`

Comment: @Arun P Johny - It has to be made into three-four.

Comment: @ Anthony Shwartz - What I listed as #1 above is one error.  It gives me a stringindexoutofbounds for that particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class NumberConversion
```

{

```
/*** Class Variables ***/

/* No class variables are needed due to the applet not having a state.
   All it does is simply convert. */

/*** Class Arrays ***/
```

char numberChar[] = { '0' , '1' , '2' , '3' , '4' ,
                         '5' , '6' , '7' , '8' , '9' };

String numberWord[] = { "zero" , "one" , "two" , "three" , "four" ,
                        "five" , "six" , "seven" , "eight" , "nine" };

```
/*** Transformer/Mutator Methods ***/
```

public String writeNumber( String phrase )
   {
        /** Local Variables **/

```
  phrase = phrase.trim();

  /*** Counts through the length of phrase ***/

    for ( int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++ )
    {

     /*** If current char is a number, count through the array
          that contains the number chars until the one needed is
          found. ***/

        if ( isNumber( phrase.charAt( i ) ) )
        {
            boolean keepSearching = true;

            int j = 0;

            do
            {
               if ( numberChar[ j ] == phrase.charAt( i ) )
                  keepSearching = false;

               else
                  j++; // Increments j if char doesn't match array element

            } while ( keepSearching && j < numberChar.length );

            /*** Replaces the current char with the corresponding String
                 word from the other number array.  ***/

            phrase = phrase.replace( Character.toString(
                                      phrase.charAt( i ) ) ,
                                      numberWord[ j ] + "-" );
    }
    }

    /*** Gets rid of dashes from unwanted places ***/

    phrase = phrase.replaceAll( "- " , " " );
    phrase = phrase.replaceAll( "-," , ", " );
    phrase = phrase.replace( "-." , "." );

    if ( phrase.charAt( phrase.length() - 1 ) == '-' )
       phrase = phrase.substring( 0 , phrase.length() - 1 );

  return phrase;
}

/*** Observer Methods ***/
```

public boolean isNumber( char input )
   {
        boolean isNumber = false; // Initially fails

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberChar.length; i++ )
    {
        /*** If input matches a number char, method returns true ***/

        if ( input == numberChar[ i ] )
           isNumber = true;
    }

    return isNumber;
}
```

Comment: Don't know why some of it didn't indent in to the code but whatever.  Anyways I figured it out.  Some minor details were changed to get what I needed after restructuring the selection statement and making one do instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Do not replace numbers in the current string, create a new string, and keep appending to it. You can then avoid a lot of unnecessary validation.

```
    List<Char> myNumberChar = Arrays.asList(numberChar);
    List<Char> myNumbers = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    StringBuilder mySB = new StringBuilder();
    //String myResultString = ""; // If you don't want to use StringBuilder
    for (int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++) {
        mySB.append(myNumbers.get(myNumberChar.getIndexOf(phrase.charAt(i)))+"-");
        //myResultString = myResultString + myNumbers.get(myNumberChar.getIndexOf(phrase.charAt(i)))+"-"; //Again, for no StringBuilder case
    }
    String myResult = mySB.toString();
    // No need to do the above in no StringBuilder case, just use myResultString in place of myResult
    System.out.println(myResult.subString(0, myResult.length - 1)); // removed the last hyphen
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try both of these.  I really don't know why I didn't think of the first.

Comment: Actually, is there a simpler way of doing what I did without list using StringBuilder? I won't be allowed to use them due to them not being covered yet in class.

Comment: You can do something like `myResultString = myResultString + myNumbers.get(myNumberChar.getIndexOf(phrase.charAt(i)))+"-";` with `myResultString` initialized to "", but that is too inefficient. String operations are costly.

Comment: I can see why StringBuilder would help in this case though.  The index error is coming from the fact I'm changing the string into something longer than the length.  If I understand what I read right on oracle's site that using the setLength() method and setting it to a high number should get me around that problem.

Comment: I'm getting really weird output using StringBuilder under my current structure.  I'm honestly stumped.  In your opinion( or anyone else that reads this ), is my entire structure bad?  I feel like that may be part of the problem.  I honestly feel no closer to getting what I need after looking at it at least 2 hours the last 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

I would use String.replace

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   str = str.replace(numberChar[i] + "", numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `replaceAll()`. Also, you missed the hyphen.

Comment: Yeah and I already had replace in there to begin with almost that exact same way anyways.